# Parentheses size on mathpazo

Tags: brackets, size, mathpazo

I noticed that using the font `mathpazo` the parentheses done with `\big(`,`\big)` or with `\left(` and `\right)` on a mid sized expression are larger than necessary and definitely larger than the corresponding ones with the default math font.

[image: Comparison]

Similarly, other delimiters are too large as well. For example, the `f(x)\big|_{x\to 0}` gives a nice looking expression with the default font, whereas it has a vertical bar too big in `mathpazo`. There's no in between: by removing `\big` the bar is of normal size and thus too small.

[image: Other comparison]

Is there any way to manually choose the size of the delimiters? Or, alternatively, do you know a font that looks similar to `mathpazo` but doesn't have this issue?

Comment: Obviously this issue will happen for all fonts, hence `\big, \bigg....` are the fixed size, but `\left` and `\right` will enclose the entire set, which size is surely higher than the `\big...`

Comment: @MadyYuvi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. My point was that with `\left` using `mathpazo` the parentheses do not adapt well to the text but are a bit too large than necessary. Whereas for `\big` already the smallest option is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`newpxmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx) and [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) with option `bb=pazo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage[bb=pazo]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbb{T}_1 = 8 \bigl( \mathbb{T}_1^0 + \mathbb{T}_{16}^0 \bigr),
\qquad
f(x) \bigr\rvert_{x\to 0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To compare the size of delimiters, where's the output of the same document, but without `newpxtext`, `newpxmath` and `mathalpha`, and with `amssymb` for the blackboard bold alphabet.

[image]

Note also that you should not use `\big`, but instead you should use `\bigl` and `\bigr` for left and right delimiters respectively.

Comment: +1 because it solves the problem I asked, however I'll wait before accepting because I don't like the `\mathcal` font of that package, so I won't probably adopt this solution. Thanks though!

Comment: @MannyC You can easily change the ``mathcal`` font (also ``mathscr`` and ``mathfrak``) with ``mathalpha``. It's explained in the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) of the package, with examples of all the fonts it allows to use. There are many available fonts with this package, so you will probably find one that you like.

Comment: Oh wow, that's awesome. Will do that later and then accept! P.S. Thanks also for the tip `\bigl` vs. `\big`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an alternative way for whomever will come across the same problem and want to stick with the mathpazo font.

The problem is that mathpazo does not have the characters for the sizes that I want, but it suffices to apply a rescaling by hand. This, by the way, only solves the issue for `\big`, `\bigl` etc. and not for `\left`/`\right`.

I took this code from [Stefan Kottwitz's answer on this forum.](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13230). Basically one can define a new parenthesis size as follows

```
\newcommand*{\bigs}[1]{\scalebox{1.1}{\ensuremath#1}} %1.1 is the scale factor
```